# Magento - Get production list: should use * (all) or specific attributes?

Tags: performance, magento

I'm trying to get product list. 
In front-end, each product needs 4-5 attributes to show.

Should I use `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addAttributeToSelect('*')` to get all attributes or just get specific attributes.

The problem is front-end may change occasionally and it will need varied attributes.

I inspect some theme and extension packages, they prefer using `addAttributeToSelect('*')` than specific one. Does it affect to performance or not?

Could you please give me some advise?

Thank you.

Comment: The * in addAttributeToSelect('*') sure affect performance as it has to join more tables

Answer (score 1):

The addAttributeToSelect permits you to define some attributes additionnally to the select defaults (entity_id, entity_type_id, type_id, sku, has_options, required_options, created_at, updated_at, is_salable, stock_item). It will of course be better to name the attributes than use *. If you develop a module, it makes sense to make it programmatically but if you just theme, best use the display scope of attributes in the different parts of the site from the backend and treat it in your theme.

Hope it helps.